# vue tiptap link extection wrong URL

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I' ve developed simple rich text input in Vue with tip tap lib. I encountered a problem however. Once I click `linked` word id doesn't redirect me to a new page but to a page with localhost andress and URL i entered. Here is how it looks. The page has reddit.com URL however when I click it it opens as "localhost:8000/reddit.com"

Here is my page deployed with Netlify ->

https://romantic-ardinghelli-dad8e5.netlify.app/

[image]

[image]

What may trigger such behavior? Here is my code with `setLink` button.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-if="editor">
     <button @click="setLink" :class="{ 'is-active': editor.isActive('link') }">
      <i class="ri-link"></i>
    </button>
    </div>
    <editor-content :editor="editor" />
  </div>
</template>
```

And following App.vue

```
<script>
import { Editor, EditorContent } from '@tiptap/vue-3'
import StarterKit from '@tiptap/starter-kit'
import Link from '@tiptap/extension-link'
import Underline from '@tiptap/extension-underline'
export default {
  components: {
    EditorContent,
  },

  data() {
    return {
      editor: null,
    }
  },

  mounted() {
    this.editor = new Editor({
      extensions: [
        StarterKit,
        Link,
        Underline
      ],
      content: `
       text here...
      `,
    })
  },

   methods: {
    setLink() {
      const url = window.prompt('URL')

      this.editor
        .chain()
        .focus()
        .extendMarkRange('link')
        .setLink({ href: url })
        .run()
    },
  },

  beforeUnmount() {
    this.editor.destroy()
  },
}
</script>
```

I was following approach here: copy pasted even.
https://www.tiptap.dev/api/marks/link/#link

Answer (score 0):

I tried it and it produced this code:

```
<a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer nofollow" href="https://www.tiptap.dev/api/marks/link/">test</a>
```

It seems to be working

Answer (score 0):

If the url set via `const url = window.prompt('URL')` looks like "reddit.com", without the protocol (http://) included, it will be treated as a relative link to somewhere on your site.

Doing some basic URL normalization (as I did on the `setLink` line below) can resolve that.

```
setLink() {
  const url = window.prompt('URL')

  this.editor
    .chain()
    .focus()
    .extendMarkRange('link')
    .setLink({ href: url.startsWith('http') ? url : `http://${url}` })
    .run()
},
```